# WiX Toolset - Is there a recommended way to handle checkboxes with silent installs

Tags: checkbox, wix

From what I understand, available states for checkboxes in WiX are (e.g. MY_PROP = "something" and MY_PROP is undefined)

The first checkbox by default was not checked, so to turn it to checked from the msiexec command line I added MY_PROP=something, and for conditions I used MY_PROP ~= "something" and NOT MY_PROP.  This seemed to work great.

Now I'm working on the opposite case (e.g. the checkbox is checked by default).  In this instance, to uncheck the checkbox, I added MY_PROP_2="" to the msiexec command line, and for conditions I used MY_PROP_2 ~= "something" and NOT MY_PROP_2.  This also worked.

I am curious, however, if there's a standard practice for handling command line options to check/uncheck a properties on the msiexec command line.  It seems like it could be confusing for the user if I ask them to turn off a checkbox by setting MY_PROP_2="" on a msiexec command line.

Is there a better way for me to handle this in Wix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not good to pass an empty value as a parameter. Instead you can pass a value to make the checkbox unchecked. Lets say if you pass value 0 as the property value, then the checkbox goes to unchecked state. Here is an example :

Your product.wxs file should have the following lines.

```
<Property Id="MY_PROP" Value="1"/>
<SetProperty Id="MY_PROP" After="AppSearch" Value="0" Sequence="first" >
      <![CDATA[MY_PROP = 0]]>
</SetProperty>
```

In your .wxs file which has the UI controls, specify the checkbox and property as below.

```
<Property Id="MY_PROP"/>
<Control Id="ChkBox" Type="CheckBox" X="120" Y="140" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Test"  Property="MY_PROP" CheckBoxValue="1" Default="no">       
</Control>
```

If you use msiexec /i MSINAME.msi MY_PROP=0 then the checkbox will be in unchecked state. Not passing the parameter value will make it to the checked state.

Comment: Thank you LeoN.  This worked great for me.  I set my values to "{}" instead of 0 to undefine the property.  Is there any reason why 0 would be a better choice, or are these just equivalent?

Comment: @sleon Zero is just a value for the example. Something like "false", "disable" will also be a good value to be used. You can use any value to make the uncheck state, as you want. Make sure you put it in your deployment guide, so users will get an understanding about the parameters passed. :)

Comment: This solution works well, BUT:
1) As @sleon commented, the value needs to be set to "{}" in the "SetProperty" tag.
2) In the UI controls WXS file, it's not necessary to specify the "Property" tag again.